# Is there any classic combinatorial optimization similar to my problem?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, algorithms

everyone. 
I try to solve a non-convex optimization problem as follows:

$$
\min_{\mathbf{x}} f\left ( \mathbf{x} \right )
$$
subject to 
$$
\sum_{i \in \mathcal{S}} x_{i} = N,
$$
$$
0\leq x_{i}\leq \lambda_{max},  \; \forall i \in \mathcal{S}.
$$
The objective function is a non-convex and non-seperable function depending on **x** and $N < \left | \mathcal{S} \right |.$ $x_{i}$ are non-negative integers and can not exceed $\lambda_{max}$. I think it's a combinatorial problem and try to use the **simulated annealing**(SA) method to resolve my problem. I think the problem is similar in concept to the classic **resource allocation problem** and common in applications; however, I can not find similar work who uses simulated annealing to deal with. In my SA algorithm, I randomly select $N$ nodes from $\mathcal{S}$ and set their values as 1. For the neighbors, I use SWAP as only operation. At each step, I randomly choose two nodes $i$ and $j$ and swap their values of $x_{i}$ and $x_{j}$. But there will some feasible solution I will never reach, for example some $x_{i}>1$. Can I add a operator that randomly choosing one node who add 1 to its value and randomly choosing one nodes whose value minus 1?

If there is any related literature I will be very grateful. Thank you very much.

**Edit**:
The objective function is as follows
$$
f\left (\mathbf{x} \right ) =  \mathrm{tr}\left( \left ( \mathbf{\Lambda}+\alpha_0 \mathbf{\Psi}^T \left( \mathbf{I}-e^{\mathrm{diag}\left ( \mathbf{x} \right )\mathbf{P}} \right) \mathbf{\Psi} \right )^{-1}\right)
$$
where $\mathbf{\Lambda,P}$ both are diagonal, square and positive definite matrices, $\alpha_0$ is a constant, $\Psi$ is an orthogonal matrix that $\mathbf{\Psi^{T}\Psi=I}$, $\mathbf{I}$ is an identity matrix. All parameters are known except $\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: What does $f(x)$ look like?

Comment: @RobPratt I add $f$ in the topics!